# file_get_contents with div class not working

Tags: php, dom

i want to extract the data from url based on class of div .i am using this code

```
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->Load('http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/3i-Infotech/Placement-  Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18433/');
$doc->getElementsByClassName('company-contentdetailes');

echo $doc;
?>
```

but i am getting nothing as output.i want to use array as well as there may be 3-4 class in one page and i want to extract all data of the class company-contentdetailes

i am getting so many errors in my errorlog when i  execute this script

```
[09-Sep-2012 04:55:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 143 and head in http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/3i-Infotech/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18433/, line: 144 in /home/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/test3.php on line 3
[09-Sep-2012 04:55:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/3i-Infotech/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18433/, line: 236 in /home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/test3.php on line 3
[09-Sep-2012 04:55:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/3i-Infotech/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18433/, line: 236 in /home/xxxxxxxxxx/test3.php on line 3
[09-Sep-2012 04:55:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: EntityRef: expecting ';' in http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/3i-Infotech/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18433/, line: 236 in /
```

so on...

Comment: Looking at the source on that page, `company-contentdetailes` does not show up **anywhere**

Comment: I think you want "company_details" from that page.

Comment: @david please check i have checked that class contains all details i mean text part of that page

Comment: @david i am getting several errors i have posted few of them as the error file is on 67kb i cant post here

Answer (score 1):

1. `getElementByClassName` is not a real DOM method. The method name is `getElementsByClassName` (note the "s" on "elements").
2. `getElementsByClassName` doesn't modify the DOM object that's passed in; it returns a set of matching DOM elements. You have to do something with this set (in this case, probably looping through it and printing the results).

Comment: i am getting several errors i have posted few of them as the error file is on 67kb i cant post here

Answer (score 0):

The document is not valid XML, there are several & that need to be encoded as `&amp;` and also unclosed meta-elements.

Comment: There are to many errors, you cannot parse this document using libxml, even when you supress the errors